# Unintended margin for ImageView

Tags: android, parse-platform

So I have a **`ParseImageView`** which is a subclass of **`ImageView`**, which is contained in a container to act as an ***overlay***. The **Visibility** of the container is statically set as GONE, but changes to VISIBLE when a cropped version of that picture inside the ScrollView is clicked.

This all works fine, but the `expanded_image_view` has **unwanted margins** on **left and right**, which crops a chunk out of the Image, and I can't seem to figure out why it happens. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/post_data">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

            <!-- some linear layouts here-->
        </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image_container"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image_view"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try to change the android:scaleType to fitXY

Comment: Hey it works! May I know why fitXY is needed? I am quite sure my image is supposed to be as big as the screen of the device.

Comment: Great! :) Ok i tried to explain what i know in the answer. Please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `android:scaleType` to `fitXY`. If you use `centerInside`, your image will be forced to be in the center and android will be cut it so it will be in the center.